# How to find a deck sealant that is compatible with some old sealant that I can't find anymore

Tags: deck, sealant, wood-finish

I am cleaning and re-sealing a wood deck. I have an old half-can of sealant that I would like to use up. 
[image: can of old sealant]

I asked the manufacturer how to find the current product, and they told me this is the one:

Olympic Wood protector waterproofing sealant toner 79002 – Honey gold  https://www.olympic.com/products/exterior-stains/olympic-wood-protector-toner

However I am having trouble finding this exact product - Lowes doesn't sell it online anymore, and it's unclear whether they sell it in store. 
http://m.lowes.com/pd/Olympic-Wood-Protector-Honey-Gold-Toner-Exterior-Stain-Actual-Net-Contents-128-fl-oz/3468547

If I can't find that exact product, how can I determine if something else is compatible with it? And would it be okay to mix the two sealants in a hand-pumped sprayer and then apply it that way?

Comment: Have you tried other retailers?  Big-box stores don't carry products consistently.  If another supplier will give them a 5 cent better price or a bigger kickback, the old brand will just disappear like it wasn't made anymore.  However lots of family owned hardware stores and lumber yards will still sell it.    If you want reliable supply, don't do business with big-box.  I don't.

Comment: @Harper thanks for the idea, but I gave up on finding an exact replacement after the answer from Chris. I only looked at Lowes originally because the Olympic website said "sold exclusively at Lowes".

Comment: Then they are telling you that they are private-labeling this product to Lowes.  Or **were**.  And they are telling you it is a close match to these other products.   Paint matching is hard.    But I agree, don't chance old stock, especially if it is water based.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your link, they sell this strictly at Lowes in Canada. I'm assuming you're not Canadian as you're using the .com instead of the .ca link for Lowes:
https://www.lowes.ca/exterior-stain/olympic-378-l-wood-protector-toner-stain-and-sealant_g1346222.html?searchTerm=Olympic-Wood-Protector-Honey-Gold-Toner-Exterior

In terms of mixing, don't. You'll waste a perfectly good can by mixing an older batch with questionable quality and an impossible to replicate colour (assuming it properly mixes).

Here are the potential situations: throwing away 20$ of stain, or spending your time applying 60$ worth only to find out you have a patchy deck/doesn't adhere to the surface forcing you to clean it all off and buy another 60$ worth followed by applying it. They could blend, but is it worth the risk?

In terms of a hand spray application, if you go with another product/brand check the labeling as some strictly avoid spray application.